# Effects of connecting speakers in parallel vs series

Tags: power, amplifier, speakers

I have two 6Ω speakers and an amp that's rated 4-6Ω. I've done some research but it's inconclusive as everyone seems to have their own way of connecting speakers.

Doing so in parallel leaves me with 3Ω so that may fry my amp, meaning I have to connect it in series. The question is **does connecting speakers in series vs parallel have an impact on volume and or sound quality?**

Comment: Yes. See "damping factor".

Comment: Get two 8 Ohm speakers.  Or a second amp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, don't connect your speakers in parallel, you might overload the amplifier.

Two speakers in series will sound a little quieter than a single speaker, for the same amplifier setting, but not very much. Although on paper the total power is halved, the ear is very non-linear to changes of level, and it will sound 'almost as loud', not 'half as loud'.

If the two loudspeakers have the same acoustic environment, then the damping factor will be no worse than for a single speaker.

Comment: I tried both and I didn't notice any volume difference at all. Series it is

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE: You have a 4-ch amp that puts out 90w at 4 ohms. Bridged you have 250w at 4 ohms. If you have 4 6x9's (450w maximum, 4 ohms each) and connect to the bridged configuration...you will have 2 sets of dual 6x9's in series and add a 250 watt 8 ohm resistor in parallel to both sets of speakers. Speakers will be 8 ohms and resistor will be 8 ohms which equates to 4 ohms. This set-up will play your speakers much louder and the amp will run slightly warmer due to the bridged/increase in power out.